# What is the correct syntax to supply parameters via the JMeter JSR223 sampler form?

Tags: jmeter, jsr223, parameter-list

I can't seem to find any docs around this, is it simple as this:

```
//option 1
${something},${something1}
//option 2
123,234,762
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Actually, it's not clear what you're asking for. Would you please explain what exactly you're trying to achieve & what difficulties you've met on the way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since [JMeter 5.2](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-released-td5728631.html) the [explanation makes more sense](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63396), not it looks like:

```
Parameters passed to script (exposed as 'Parameters' (type String) and 'args' (type String[]))
```

So if you want to reference the whole line you provide in the "Parameters" section as a single [String](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html) just use `Parameters`.

If you want to access individual entries (separated by whitespace) you can use `args[0]` for the first parameter, `args[1]` for the second, etc.

Demo:

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Comment: Thank you so much for the response and being so helpful 

Answer (score -1):

Consider the script inside the sampler as your `public static void main(String[] args)`.

So, you've got your good 'ol Java `args` to mess with (I'm not going to elaborate on that, that's basics).

In addition, JMeter puts the raw string as you see it in the box into a pre-set `String` variable called `Parameters` -  so you can parse it yourself the way you please.

And certainly, JMeter variable referenses/functions are being evaluated if put into parameters list.